# Python, nestes list comprehensions

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm writing some code and have come across a problem.

Code example:

```
my_list_1 = [
            [1, 2, 3], 
            [1, 2, 3], 
            [1, 2, 3]
            ]

my_list_2 = []

for index, list in enumerate(my_list_1):
    my_list_2.append([])
    for item in list:
        my_list_2[index].append("Hello World")

print(my_list_2)

[['Hello World', 'Hello World', 'Hello World'], ['Hello World', 'Hello World', 'Hello World'], ['Hello World', 'Hello World', 'Hello World']]
```

I want to write this for-loop as a list comprehension but I never succeed.

Do any of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the following, as `my_list_2[index]` was just assigning to the just created list

```
my_list_2 = [
    ["Hello World" for _ in sublist]
    for sublist in my_list_1
]
```

---

For the classic loop version, something a bit easier is

```
my_list_2 = []
for sublist in my_list_1:
    tmp_list = []
    for item in sublist:
        tmp_list.append(f"Hello World {item}")
    my_list_2.append(tmp_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

That was exactly what I was looking for :)

Have a nice day!

Comment: These list comprehensions are a bit complicated I think but I like them. In what situations do you use list comperhenions and not for-loops?

Comment: @Usagi-Dev list comprehension can be used when you want to collect into a list as result and may need modification of filtering on each object. when you just need to do multiple actions then use a classic for loop , as you don't need to collect anything

Comment: Ok, i get it! Thank you so much for your help and time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can nest list comprehensions:

```py
my_list_2 = [['hello world' for i in lst] for lst in my_list_1]
```